# Insert a Reply for a Comment in docx using docx4j

Tags: java, docx, docx4j

Hi I am using `docx4j` I am creating a `comment` for specific `paragraph` using [ref](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/CommentsSample.java) but I want to create a `reply` for `comment` i.e `comment` for `comment` in `docx` using `docx4j`. I can't find solution for it, help me to find solution. Thanks in advance to replies.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my comment on your issue https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/issues/210

To understand the structure you need to replicate, have a look at a suitable document (created in Word 2013/2016).

If you write some working code, consider posting it here as an answer.  If you can't figure it out, please add the code you've tried to this question...